# POST на AJAX

Tags: ajax, javascript, html, textarea, форма

У меня имеется текстовое поле textarea.
Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на Enter данные этой формы отправлялись методом POST в файл "ajax.php". Как вы поняли, выполнить это нужно с помощью js и ajax.

```
<script>
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

function sendAjax(textSend){
if((event.keyCode==10)||(event.keyCode==13)) {
/************************************/
}
textSend.value='';
}
</script>
<textarea onkeydown="sendAjax(this)"></textarea>
```

вместо этих звездочек нужно поставить необходимый код. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так, ajax асинхронный:

```
var request = getXmlHttp(); // глобальная переменная

request.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
          var serverResponse = this.responseText;
          // alert(serverResponse); // -> ответ сервера
          // тут можно как-то продолжить цепочку событий ...
          // например очистить textarea
          document.getElementById("yourTextAreaId").value = '';
     }
}

// тело if'a
var texterea = document.getElementById("yourTextAreaId");
if(textarea.value != '') { // если значение не пустое
     request.open("POST", "/yourScript.php", true);
     request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     request.send("textareaData=" + textarea.value);
     // на сервер прийдет $_POST['textareaData']
}
```

---

Для передачи нескольких параметров в request.send надо писать как-то так:

```
  request.send("param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 .... ");
```

Вообще для этих целей лучше всего написать функцию, типо

```
function prepareParams(paramsObj) {
     var paramsString = '';
     for(i in paramsObj) {
            paramsString += i + "=" + paramsObj[i] + "&";
     }
     return paramsString.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Применять как-то так:

```
request.send(prepareParams({
      param1 : "value1",
      param2 : "value2",
      param3 : "value3"
       ..........
      paramN : "valueN"

}));
```

В приведенном вами примере:

```
 request.send(prepareParams({
      textareaData : textarea.value,
      textareaData2 : textarea2.value
 }));
```